# Symfony2 abstract structure

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I can't seem to figure out how to get this working with Symfony2 forms.

My database structure looks like this :
(i'm using the hasOne, hasMany notation for simplification and understanding)

```
Object (this is the class name)
    hasOne ObjectType
    hasMany ObjectValues
    response

ObjectType
    hasMany ObjectTypeFields
    name

ObjectTypeField
    name
    datatype

ObjectValue
    hasOne Object
    hasOne ObjectTypeField
    value
```

From the above defined structure, I have an ObjectType called "Appointment" let's say. This ObjectType has two related fields (in ObjectTypeField) : let's say, "date" and "time".

So if I do $objectType->getFields(), I get two objects named "date" and "time" respectively.

I have a form class for my Object Class (ObjectType.php in Bundle/Form/Type). When I create a new Object, I want the form to have all the properties present in the Object class but also the ObjectTypeField properties which are related through the ObjectType class. So, my goal if I create a new "Appointment" object, is to have a form that has fields for "response" which is part of the Object object but also "date" and "time" which are related fields through the ObjectType of my "Appointment" object. Obviously, the values of these 2 fields can't be saved to the Object object because those properties don't exist there. They should be saved as ObjectValues related to the Object and the ObjectTypeField...

I don't understand how to do this with embedded forms because of the variable properties and where they have to be saved.

Anybody have an idea? I'm on Symfony 2.3.6 with Doctrine.

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you structuring your model like this? It seems overly-generic, and doesn't really lend itself to Symfony's forms (or most of Doctrine's ORM features, for that matter...). Usually when you construct your model, you'd have more concrete classes... so for example, a email management application might have `Mailbox`, `Message`, `User`, etc.

Comment: @ThomasKelley , true, this is overly generic. The reason I want to use this structure is that my App class (the class which use the Object classes) is generic and doesn't have to or even can't know about the object structure... I mean, I could have an "Appointment" class and a "Prescription" class but then the problem is that my App class would have to know about the different Object classes and their methods. This is actually how I'm set up right now. Just trying to figure out a way to have the structure so it's as generic as possible.

Comment: I've been looking into other ways of accomplishing the same objective but using a better design. Looking at single table inheritance, i found an article by Tim Nagel talking about "PolyCollections". Thinking about using this https://github.com/infinite-networks/InfiniteFormBundle which seems to do exactly what I want but using a much simpler structure. Any opinions? Thanks!